# Is there an Update Object holder on Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I'm currently **inserting/updating** fields like this (if there's a better way, please say so - we're always learning)

```
public void UpdateChallengeAnswers(List<ChallengeAnswerInfo> model, Decimal field_id, Decimal loggedUserId)
{
    JK_ChallengeAnswers o;
    foreach (ChallengeAnswerInfo a in model)
    {
        o = this.FindChallengeAnswerById(a.ChallengeAnswerId);
        if (o == null) o = new JK_ChallengeAnswers();

        o.answer = FilterString(a.Answer);
        o.correct = a.Correct;
        o.link_text = "";
        o.link_url = "";
        o.position = FilterInt(a.Position);

        o.updated_user = loggedUserId;
        o.updated_date = DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (o.challenge_id == 0)
        {
            // New record
            o.challenge_id = field_id;  // FK
            o.created_user = loggedUserId;
            o.created_date = DateTime.UtcNow;

            db.JK_ChallengeAnswers.AddObject(o);
        }
        else
        {
            // Update record
            this.Save();
        }
    }

    this.Save(); // Commit changes
}
```

As you can see **there is 2 times** `this.Save()` (witch invokes `db.SaveChanges();`)

when **Adding** we place the new object into a **Place Holder**  with the `AddObject` method, in other words, the new object is not committed right away and we can place as many objects we want.

But when it's an update, I need to Save first before moving on to the next object, is there a method that I can use in order to, let's say:

```
        if (o.challenge_id == 0)
        {
            // New record
            o.challenge_id = field_id;
            o.created_user = loggedUserId;
            o.created_date = DateTime.UtcNow;

            db.JK_ChallengeAnswers.AddObject(o);
        }
        else
        {
            // Update record
            db.JK_ChallengeAnswers.RetainObject(o);
        }
    }

    this.Save(); // Only save once when all objects are ready to commit
}
```

So if there are 5 updates, I don't **need to save into the database 5 times**, but only once at the end.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you have an object which is attached to the graph, if you **modify** values of this object, then the entity is marked as **Modified**.

If you simply do `.AddObject`, then the entity is marked as **Added**.

Nothing has happened yet - only staging of the graph.

**Then**, when you execute `SaveChanges()`, EF will translate the entries in the OSM to relevant store queries.

Your code looks a bit strange. Have you debugged through (and ran a SQL trace) to see what is actually getting executed? Because i can't see why you need that first `.Save`, because inline with my above points, since your modifying the entities in the first few lines of the method, an UPDATE statement will most likely *always* get executed, regardless of the ID.

I suggest you refactor your code to handle new/modified in seperate method. (ideally via a Repository)

Comment: got it, there is no need to hold anything, the EF knows that :) regarding refactoring.. dang! no way, I can refactor more, if I refactor this I will have doubles again ... this is perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Employee Info Starter Kit](http://eisk.codeplex.com/), you can consider the code snippet as below:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(Employee updatedEmployee)
        {
            //attaching and making ready for parsistance
            if (updatedEmployee.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
                _DatabaseContext.Employees.Attach(updatedEmployee);
            _DatabaseContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(updatedEmployee, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            _DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```